# Debugging web application in service fabric - View error returns 404

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I'm developing a web application (ASP.Net Core) in a servicefabric cluster, but every time I get an error in a razor view (for example a variable not set) I get a 404 error and not the well known error page which tells me *what* is wrong.

I have no clue as to why it does that or how I should solve it and can't find anything online. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The project used to run outside the cluster and debugging worked there but since it's in the cluster it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio is currently not able to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for Service Fabric Services.

You can workaround this problem by changing this code in the default Configuration method in your Startup.cs file to this:

```
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())            
            if (env.ContentRootPath.Contains("SfDevCluster"))
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
```

That should be a fairly safe assumption that you are running the application in a OneBox Service Fabric cluster.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks